# Backtrackig issue

Tags: c++, computer-science

Given two integers, *n* and *k*, return all possible combinations of *k* numbers out of 1 2 3 ... *n*. Make sure the combinations are sorted.

My code is as follows:

```cpp
void answer(vector<vector<int>> op, vector<int> temp, int index, int A, int B){

    if(!B){
        op.push_back(temp);
        return;
    }

    for(int i=index; i<=(A-B+1); i++){
        temp.push_back(i);
        answer(op, temp, i+1, A, B-1);
        temp.pop_back();
    }
    return;
}

vector<vector<int> > Solution::combine(int A, int B) {
    
    vector<int> temp;
    vector<vector<int>> op;
    
    if(B>A)
        return op;
    answer(op, temp, 1, A, B);
    return op;
}
```

It doesn't even pass the trivial case for A=B=1 as it returns NULL rather than the output [1].

Comment: Try to create a [mcve] which uses these functions, and hard-code the data that makes it fail. Then use a debugger to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. That's the normal way to find and fix errors like this.

Answer (score 1):

The argument `vector<vector<int>> op` is an **copy of** what is passed, so the result of `op.push_back` will not appear on the callers.

You should add `&` and use reference `vector<vector<int>>& op` instead.

Also `vector<int> temp` should be reference `vector<int>& temp` to improve performance.

Comment: Oh my god! Thank you so much! So so much!